# xhci_pci not working with Fedora 33 on RaspberryPi4

Tags: fedora, boot, raspberry-pi, arm

I'm trying to run Fedora 33 on a RaspberryPi 4b (4GB).

I'm using `fedora-arm-image-installer` to prepare the SD Card:

```
fedora-arm-image-installer --image=Fedora-Minimal-armhfp-33-1.2-sda.raw.xz --target=rpi4 --media=/dev/sdX --resizefs
```

When booting, I get (paraphrased):

```
xhci_pci: Host not halted after 16000 microseconds.
[...]
Probe failed, errno -16
No controller found.
[...]
Press any key to stop autoboot
```

I don't get any further - it seems that the sd card isn't detected and the rootfs can't be loaded.

[There seems to be a quirk with `xhci_hcd`](https://leo3418.github.io/2020/09/20/raspi4-fedora-usb-simple.html) that can be fixed by limiting the memory to 3gb:

```
total_mem=3072
```

But that didn't help in my case.
I also found this [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1939023) (but it seems to be created from a running system).

Am I missing something?